# Custom TFS Check-In Policy: "Uncheck" a checked pending change during evaluation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, checkin-policy

I have an Check-In-Policy extension for VS2017 (using TFS 2017) that checks if the pending check-in contains files matching a given regex.
In case matching files are contained in `CheckedPendingChanges` the `Evaluate` method returns the `PolicyFailure` to avoid checking in these files.

```
[Serializable]
public class FileWarningPolicy : PolicyBase
{
   // ...

   public override PolicyFailure[] Evaluate()
   {
        Regex regex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (PendingCheckin.Policies.EvaluationState != PolicyEvaluationState.Evaluated) return new PolicyFailure[0];                
        var matchingFiles = from change in PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChanges                                   
                            where change.IsEdit && regex.IsMatch(change.ServerItem)
                            select change;               

        return matchingFiles.Any()
               ? new [] { new PolicyFailure("some error message", this)
               : new PolicyFailure[0];

    }
}
```

This works fine. But it would be far more comfortable if I were able to simply "uncheck" these files to **exclude them from the current check-in but not abort the whole check-in.**

Through the `PendingCheckin.PendingChanges` property I have access to the current [`Workspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb171783(v=vs.120)) which has a lot of methods to download, check-in, check-out, shelve etc. the repository items, but nothing to only uncheck/exclude them from the checked pending changes (only to add an exclude entry to `.tfignore`, which is not what I want).

Is there a way to achieve this?